# How can i change style of one element mouseovering on another?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to change style of WORK div when hovering at one of the hexagons. I've put them all into a table as a container, but it doesn;t seem to work.
Maybe you can give me a hint, thank you.

Example

Comment: [Example*](http://jsfiddle.net/K7JDs/12/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your point the answer is "You cannot with current schema."

You shall use `+` or `~` selector. They works if elements have the same parent so you can apply CSS rule if any of hexagon is hovered but you cannot determine particular one.

Add the rule to your example to see what i'm saying:

```
*:hover + * > * > .work-box{
     border: solid red;
}
```

If your elements have the same parent solution is quite simple - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AeqK9/)

There is good site for Russian speakers [about ~ selector](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/sibling)

Comment: One more, if you want to solve the problem without changing HTML schema then you should use JavaScript.

Comment: It's good that i'm russian :) Thank you, i'll look it trough.

Comment: It was spotted due to comments in Russian language at CSS :)

Comment: Yey, i've made it, maybe not in the most elegant way http://jsfiddle.net/AeqK9/3/ :) Rearranged the acheme a little bit. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just answered another question like this (but was specific to a task). I shall use the same example so you can have a look at how it works.

You can do this just using CSS:

### HTML:

```
<img name="image1" src="./goal/images/normalButton.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width : 183px;" />

<h2 class="mnrImageH2"><span class = "mnrImageSpan">Haberler</span></h2>
```

### CSS:

```
.mnrImageH2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.mnrImageSpan {
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
h2 {
    color: white;
}
img:hover + h2 {
    color: #000;
}
```

So using the `+` selector we can select the `h2` when we hover over an `img`. Take this and do what you need to do with it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/TGJGU/)

Comment: Nice, you can clean up more by transferring the inline styles to stylesheet :) and also would like to point out that demo won't work, you have a relative URL there

Comment: @Mr.Alien It was the link the other guy was using. Like I said its the same demo I did for that one. Don't matter too much as it still works. :D

Comment: I know it works, some users have tendency here, that it doesn't work, go, cast a downvote :) cuz particularly in this case, demo is useless without an image

Comment: @Mr.Alien Are you on drugs? Lol.

Comment: Nothing... nothing at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you in your problem and if you are not satisfy by this then comment on this post i will try to solve that also.

```
<div>
    <div class="e" >Company</div>
    <div class="e">Target</div>
    <div class="e" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>         
<div class="f">
    <div class="e">Company</div>
    <div class="e">Target</div>
    <div class="e" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>
```

And use hover like this,
    .e
    {
        width:90px;
        border-right:1px solid #222;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        padding-left:2px;
        cursor:pointer;

```
}
.f .e
{
    background-color:#F9EDBE;

}
.e:hover{
   background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you,  but that's not quite what i've been looking for. As you can see from the example that i have posted above, i need to connect hexagons with WORK box, so it's design and content would change depending on wich hexagon i am hovering